# Scene Builder: Failed to load FXML file

Tags: javafx

I am Loading a Fxml file in scene builder and it's showing me the below error. I had external date picker code and i have commented it all still it's showing the error. Any help would be appreciable.

Loading of `xyz.fxml` has failed. Make sure it is a valid fxml file.

```
error: java.lang.UnSupportedOperationException
```

**FXML**

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="view" " xmlns:fx="javafx.com/fxml"; fx:controller="com.nubes.labour.controller.DataSyncController">
    <children>
        <TextField fx:id="hoursText" layoutX="451.0" layoutY="342.0" prefWidth="45.0" />
        <!-- <DatePicker id="toDatePick" fx:id="toDate" layoutX="448.0" layoutY="297.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="140.0" /> -->
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Can you post the FXML file? Preferably reduce it to something small that still generates the error.

Comment: Hi james find the below. Is there any problem with the below code, <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="view" " xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="com.nubes.labour.controller.DataSyncController">
  <children>    <TextField fx:id="hoursText" layoutX="451.0" layoutY="342.0" prefWidth="45.0" />   <!--  <DatePicker id="toDatePick" fx:id="toDate" layoutX="448.0" layoutY="297.0" prefHeight="26.0"  prefWidth="140.0" /> -->  </children>
</AnchorPane>

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple issues in your fxml. It has an unwanted `;` and `"`. The `xmlns` is also incorrect. I am not sure if you have the imports or just missed them while editing. Try the following fxml:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="view" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.nubes.labour.controller.DataSyncController">
    <children>
        <TextField fx:id="hoursText" layoutX="451.0" layoutY="342.0" prefWidth="45.0" />
        <!-- <DatePicker id="toDatePick" fx:id="toDate" layoutX="448.0" layoutY="297.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="140.0" /> -->
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working know. I really appreciate you.